# which fields should go in an index?

Tags: database, hibernate, postgresql, indexing, hql

I hae a query in a postgresql database which takes too much time and I like to add an index to make it quicker, but I don't know which fields shouls I include in the index cause many of them belong to other tables and some of them are Foreign keys.

I'm using hibernate and the HQL query is this one:

```
SELECT i FROM Item i 
LEFT JOIN i.model.kind AS k 
LEFT JOIN i.model.kind.subkind AS s
WHERE i.file is null " +
AND i.identifier is not null
AND i.identifier != ''
AND i.place is not null 
AND i.place.id = :placeId
AND ( upper(i.serial) LIKE upper(:keyword)
    OR upper(i.code)  LIKE upper(:keyword)
    OR upper(i.law.law)  LIKE upper(:keyword) 
    OR upper(i.model.model)  LIKE upper(:keyword) 
    OR upper(k.kind)  LIKE upper(:keyword) 
    OR upper(s.subkind)  LIKE upper(:keyword) 
    OR upper(i.model.factory.factory) LIKE upper(:keyword) 
)
ORDER BY i.code, i.id
```

The schema of the database is generated automatically from the model which looks like the one I include below.

Which fields shouls I include in the index?

Thanks.

```
public class Item {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String identifier;
    private String code;
    private String serial;

    @ManyToOne
    private File file;

    @ManyToOne
    private Law law;

    @ManyToOne
    private Place place;

    @ManyToOne
    private Model model;
}

public class File {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String file;
}

public class Law {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String law;
}

public class Place {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String place;
}   

public class Model {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String model;

    @ManyToOne
    private Factory factory;

    @ManyToOne
    private Kind kind;
}

public class Factory {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String factory;
}   

public class Kind {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String kind;

    @ManyToOne
    private Subkind subkind;
}

public class Subkind {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String subkind;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're having performance problems on nested fulltext searches, you may want to dive into Hibernate Search.

Hibernate search (which uses Lucene) allows fast and efficient fulltext searches, also on properties of nested objects.

Looking at youre current query, Postgresql may not even use an index if you place textplaceholders on both sides (%keyword% does not use the same execution plan as keyword%)

Comment: What you're trying to do is better suited to Lucene, it is nearly impossible to optimize a traditional DBMS index to work with a bunch of text searches and or clauses... you'll always need to scan the entire contents of all the indexes.